# "Succeeded out of luck" and "Is out of luck" To be out of luck

Tags: word-usage

I understand the usage, but "out of luck" itself I don't quite grasp. Where does it come from?

I want to know the etymology of "out of" in the sense of not having.

Comment: There are three seemingly related phrases in your title, with vastly different meanings, and your question doesn’t really tell us what it is you don’t understand. Please elaborate and clarify what it is you’re asking.

Comment: Read that as 'succeeded out of' + 'luck', not 'succeeded' + 'out of luck'.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about ELU but parsing a sentence correctly. 

Comment: What @Kris said. This question would be a better fit on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). FWIW, when referring to *succeeding **through/because of** luck*, it's more usually ***by***, not ***out of***. Here are 155 instances in Google Books of [**by luck** rather than judgement](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22by+luck+rather+than+judgement%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). There are none at all for the same phrase using ***out of luck***.

Comment: This is the same _out of_ as in _run out of_; i.e, to lack, possibly only temporarily, something one ordinarily possesses. If you're out of toilet paper, don't use the restroom; if you're out of luck, don't try anything dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not entirely clear without the context, but *out of luck* probably means that the enterprise succeeded **as a result of** good luck. One of the meanings of *out of* is ‘from (something) as a cause or motive; as the result or effect of; because or by reason of.’

Comment: But Barrie, how about the "is out of luck"?

Comment: _To be out of luck_ usually means not to have any luck. But if something succeeds _out of luck_ it means it succeeds, as I said, as a result of luck. It might be easier to explain with the full context in which it occurs.

Comment: Ok. I am wondering how "I don't have luck" becomes "I am out of luck"

Comment: If you are _out of_ something, it means you have no more of it.

Comment: Zooming in... the etymology of "out of" in the sense of not having. The other one I understood.

Comment: I don't know if it's true but I would think it comes from a store being out of stock "The nails are all sold out, sorry, we are out of nails now."

Comment: Probably not. The OED’s earliest citation for _out of_ in this sense is from around 1500. There are two citations from Shakespeare: 'These English are shrowdly out of Beefe’ and ‘I am out a [of] friends Madam.’